# MvxBind:Error: 10.40 Exception thrown during the view binding

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to create a simple service using the code provided but i don't understand why have an exception when binding.

10-19 11:42:09.148 I/mono-stdout( 1622): MvxBind:Error: 10.40 Exception thrown during the view binding

MvxBindingLayoutInflatorFactory Line 133!

I need some help please :)

My Source:

DataStore Interface:

```
using Core.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IDataStore
    {
        void UpdateFeed(FeedModel feedModel);
        void DeleteFeed(FeedModel feedModel);
        void CreateFeed(FeedModel feedModel);
        FeedModel GetFeed(Uri uri);
        ObservableCollection<FeedModel> Feeds { get; }
    }
}
```

DataStore Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Core.Interfaces;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.ServiceProvider;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.Platform;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.Localization;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ExtensionMethods;
using Core.Helpers;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace Core.Models
{
    public class DataStore
        : IDataStore
        , IMvxServiceConsumer<IMvxSimpleFileStoreService>
        , IMvxServiceConsumer<IMvxResourceLoader>
    {
        public DataStore()
        {
            Load();
        }

        public void UpdateFeed(FeedModel feedModel)
        {
            var toUpdate = this.m_feeds.First(feed => feed.Url == feedModel.Url);
            toUpdate.CloneFrom(feedModel);
            Save();
        }

        public void DeleteFeed(FeedModel feedModel)
        {
            this.m_feeds.Remove(this.m_feeds.First(feed => feed.Url == feedModel.Url));
            Save();
        }

        public void CreateFeed(FeedModel feedModel)
        {
            this.m_feeds.Add(feedModel);
            Save();
        }

        public FeedModel GetFeed(Uri uri)
        {
            return this.m_feeds.First(feed => feed.Url == uri);
        }

        private void Load()
        {
            var fileService = this.GetService<IMvxSimpleFileStoreService>();
            if (!fileService.TryReadBinaryFile(LocationDataService.StoreFileName, LoadFrom))
            {
                var resourceLoader = this.GetService<IMvxResourceLoader>();
                resourceLoader.GetResourceStream(LocationDataService.ResourceFileName, (inputStream) => LoadFrom(inputStream));
            }
        }

        private bool LoadFrom(Stream inputStream)
        {
            try
            {
                var loadedData = XDocument.Load(inputStream);
                if (loadedData.Root == null)
                    return false;

                using (var reader = loadedData.Root.CreateReader())
                {
                    var list = (List<FeedModel>)new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<FeedModel>)).Deserialize(reader);
                    this.m_feeds = new ObservableCollection<FeedModel>(list);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void Save()
        {
            var fileService = this.GetService<IMvxSimpleFileStoreService>();
            fileService.WriteFile(LocationDataService.StoreFileName, (stream) =>
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<FeedModel>));
                serializer.Serialize(stream, m_feeds.ToList());
            });
        }

        private ObservableCollection<FeedModel> m_feeds;
        public ObservableCollection<FeedModel> Feeds
        {
            get { return this.m_feeds; }
        }

    }
}
```

BaseViewModel:

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Commands;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ExtensionMethods;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.Commands;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.ServiceProvider;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using Core.Interfaces;

namespace Core.ViewModels
{
    public class BaseViewModel
        : MvxViewModel
        , IMvxServiceConsumer<IDataStore>
    {
        protected IDataStore DataStore
        {
            get { return this.GetService<IDataStore>(); }
        }
    }
}
```

FeedManagerViewModel:

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Commands;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.Commands;
using Core.Controls;
using Core.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Core.ViewModels
{
    public class FeedsManagerViewModel
        : BaseViewModel
    {

        public ObservableCollection<FeedModel> Feeds { get { return this.DataStore.Feeds; } }

       ...
    }
}
```

View xml:

```
<Mvx.MvxBindableListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Feeds'}, 'ItemClick':{'Path':'DisplayItemCommand'}}"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/feedlist_viewmodel" />
```

Comment: what's the exception? any more output trace available? what does feedlist_viewModel.axml look like? If you put a breakpoint on line 133 of that file, then does it tell you anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an error in your XML... but it's hard to tell from just that one line of trace.

What version of MvvmCross are you running?

The tip version of both Master and vNext show line 133 as

```
  MvxBindingTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "Exception during creation of {0} from type {1} - exception {2}", name, viewType.FullName, exception.ToLongString());
```

So hopefully if you use the tip, then that should give you a lot more information about what is going wrong.

Beyond that, you can always try setting a breakpoint on the offending line to extract more information.

---

If the exception is on line 99 then change the error logging there from:

```
MvxBindingTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "Exception thrown during the view binding ", exception.ToLongString());
```

to:

```
MvxBindingTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "Exception thrown during the view binding {0}", exception.ToLongString());
```

The error will be in there somewhere :)

---

Another good debugging technique is to comment out lines one-by-one until the problem goes away - this helps identify where the problem is.

You've got a working development environment and a really powerful debugger - using it is a good skill to learn. 'Code Complete' is one of my favourite books ever :)